# Dojango with django 1.5

Tags: django, json

I'm a django noob. I just added dojango 0.5.5 in project apps. I use Django 1.5 and when i try to vie the test page dojango offers at mysite/dojango/test/ i got this error:

```
__init__() got an unexpected keyword argument 'namedtuple_as_object'
```

the error is in the dojango base template file where there is:

```
'isDebug':{{ DOJANGO.DEBUG|json }},
```

Has someone encountered this issue? How do you resolve it?

Comment: Can you add a full traceback, please?

Comment: I solved the problem: in django 1.5 simplejson is deprecated so I changed dojango to import json instead of simplejson

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found a [similar issue](https://github.com/brack3t/django-braces/pull/25). Try to find

```
from django.utils import simplejson as json
```

and replace it with

```
try:
    import json
except ImportError:
   from django.utils import simplejson as json
```

Comment: Thank you, i just found the solution exploring the source code and found out simplejson is depracated